# 404 Page Not Found codeigniter controller not working after change its name

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

Hi I'm working on CodeIgniter base website everything is work fine but I want to change its controller name and model name for SEO it will show an error.Thanks in advance
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkpnl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change controller name or function inside it. Use `routes` instead if that

In [**`application/config/routes.php`**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php) define custom route

**Example**

```
$route['contact-us'] = 'welcome/contact';
```

and in URL hit

```
https://stackoverflow.com/contact-us
            ^ Base URL       ^ Route
```